# Get polygon area using HERE maps

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using HERE maps and I would like to know the area of a polygon drawn on the map. Is there a way to know that? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I dont think there exists any function to provide you the area of the polygon. Probabaly you can explain your user case in detail. If your usecase is about finding whether a coordinate is inside the polygon area then you can refer http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#is-point-within-a-polygon

Comment: No, the usecase is exactly to know the area of a polygon in squared meters or squared yards or other units of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function within the JS API but you can easily do it yourself.
Below is provided a sample function for computing the area (in square meters) of a polygonal area:

```
function computeArea(latLngs) {
    var pointsCount = latLngs.length,
            area = 0.0,
            d2r = Math.PI / 180.0,
            radius = 6378137.0,
            p1, p2;

    if (pointsCount <= 2)
        return 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        p1 = latLngs[i];
        p2 = latLngs[(i + 1) % pointsCount];
        area += ((p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * d2r) *
                (2 + Math.sin(p1.lat() * d2r) + Math.sin(p2.lat() * d2r));
    }
    area = area * radius * radius / 2.0;
    return Math.abs(area);
}
```